# round in mysql doesn't work very well

Tags: mysql, rounding

The round function sometime doesn't work very well. I have in my db a row like this:

```
field_1= 375
field_2= 0.65
field_3= 0.1 
field_4= 11
```

So we know that: field_1*field_2*field_3*field_4 = 268.125 so if I round it to 2 decimals -> 268.13.

But in mysql I got 268.12 -> Select round(field_1*field_2*field_3*field_4) from my table   -> 268.12

This situation just happens with these values, I tried with other numbers and no problem the round works.

Any workaround about it. I tried in mysql 4.1.22, and 5.1.44 and I get the same issue. I read in other forum http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6251 that it is not a bug, they said that it depends on the C library implementation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What data type are you using for those columns?

If you want exact precision then you should use `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL`, not `FLOAT`, `REAL`, or `DOUBLE`.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html):

```
The DECIMAL and NUMERIC types store exact numeric data values. 
These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, 
for example with monetary data.
```

Answer (score 0):

If applicable you can use `FLOOR()`

If not applicable you will be better off handling this on the application side. I.e. do the entire calculation application side and then round, or just round application side.

`SELECT (field_1*field_2*field_3*field_4) AS myCalculation FROM my table`

Comment: I have a lot of math in my application, do that with mysql is faster than server side. but thanks for your suggestion.